# Aligning Text In JtextArea in java

Tags: java, swing

I need to add items in a JtextArea and with its Description and a Price but i have a problem in aligning it. i want  an output of this is like

```
Description          Price
Coffe                $50.00
Bread                $30.00
Egg                  $10.00
```

but my Program makes like

```
Description           Price
Coffe           $50
Bread                 $30
Egg                 $20
```

Anyone pls help me how to Align it?....

```
txtArea.append( "\n" + desc+"         " + price + "         " + quanty);
```

Comment: Yep, use a JTable. If you absolutely can't use a JTable, then make sure that you use a mono-spaced Font, such as `Font.MONOSPACED`, and then use `String.format(...)` not tabs.

Comment: I tried to use a jtable and it works fine.. but my problem is in JtextArea i cant align it... i used JtextArea instead of Jtable because i want to print the text on what is inside the JtextArea so it will work like A receipt.

Answer (score 3):

***HTML*** In a JTextPane rather than JTextArea one could use HTML:

```
<html><table><tr><th>Description</th><th>....<tr><td>...
```

With CSS styles the most beautiful, requiring some effort.

***String.format*** With a fixed-size font (monospaced) in a JTextArea one can do:

```
txtArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
txtArea.append(String.format("%-30s %15s %10d\n", desc, price, quanty));
```

- %-30s left aligned string
- %15s right aligned string
- %10d right aligned integer

Comment: It seems that your answer is Right sir but Im just a newbie in java and i havent tried to use jtextpane. and i did what you answered but it makes me mad on some errors that occur.. can you pls site another example sir? thank you..

Comment: I was meaning, that HTML would be _one_ solution, but with JTextArea there is a _second_ solution, using `String.format`, Sorry for overcomplicating things.

Comment: its ok sir.. i tried it again and again... but i cant still get the right thing to align it, by the way sir i just want to use the JtextArea for printing a receipt.. but i think its not good to use JtextArea for printing a receipt. can u pls refer me a link or code how to make a receipt sir? thanks for taking time to answer my question.

Comment: I have added a `setFont` for a fixed-sized font, where every letter has the same width. Maybe that was the problem? For printing a receipt HTML is a better option (drawing lines, several fonts). In general swing components like JTextArea can be printed.

Comment: Finally......  Done. instead of
 txtArea.append(String.format("%-30s %15s %10d\n", desc, price, quanty));. 

i tried 

txtArea.append(String.format("\n" +"%-30s", desc));
txtArea.append(String.format(" %15s ", price));
txtArea.append(String.format(" %10d ", quanty));

 thank you so much @Joop Eggen..

Comment: 1+, @NoobProgrammer, don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.